# PHP average values in array based on matched values of another key

Tags: php, arrays

I have tested numerous answers from other questions, but a solution to my problem remains elusive. Any assistance would be most appreciated.

I have this array:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '34',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '8',
    1 => '51',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '72',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => '8',
    1 => '38',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '80',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => '3',
    1 => '56',
  ),
)
```

I want to average the values of the second key[1] where values of the first key[0] are matching. This would be the desired result:

```
array (
  0 => '62',       // the average of '34, 72, 80'
  1 => '44.5',     // the average of '51, 38'
  2 => '56',       // the average of '56'
)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$result = array_reduce
(
    $array,
    function( $carry, $item )
    {
        if( ! isset($carry[$item[0]]) ) $carry[$item[0]] = [ 'values'=>[$item[1]], 'avg'=>$item[1] ];
        else
        {
            $carry[$item[0]]['values'][] = $item[1];
            $carry[$item[0]]['avg']      = array_sum( $carry[$item[0]]['values'])/count($carry[$item[0]]['values'] );
        }
        return $carry;
    },
    array()
);

print_r( $result );
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 34
                    [1] => 72
                    [2] => 80
                )
            [avg] => 62
        )
    [8] => Array
        (
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 51
                    [1] => 38
                )

            [avg] => 44.5
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 56
                )
            [avg] => 56
        )
)
```

<kbd>**[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/550708)**</kbd>

If you are not interested in preserving keys:

```
$result = array_values( $result );
```

If you want only the averages:

```
$result = array_column( $result, 'avg' );
```

With [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) we recreate the array progressively adding the values to respective index key and calculating relative average.

You can obtain same result with a `foreach` loop:

```
$result = array();
foreach( $array as $key => $val )
{
    if( ! isset($result[$item[0]]) ) $result[$item[0]] = [ 'values'=>[$item[1]], 'avg'=>$item[1] ];
    else
    {
        $result[$item[0]]['values'][] = $item[1];
        $result[$item[0]]['avg']      = array_sum( $result[$item[0]]['values'])/count($result[$item[0]]['values'] );
    }
}
```